# c++ reset a member of a struct thats an array of structs

Tags: c++, struct

so i have an struct that contains an array of structs, im wondering how to reset the array of structs without reseting the rest of the members of the first struct.
this is my code for the structs:

```
struct Card {
    int value;
    char type[10];
};

struct Wallet {
    double money;
    Card cards[11];
    int cardIndex;
};
```

so far i have tried    `delete[]` and `memset` however both aren't seem to work. any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `delete[]` and `memset` do totally different things. From what you have show `memset` seems like it would be right. You need to define what you mean by "reset".

Comment: To hold a string, use `std::string`. To hold a constant number of items, use `std::array`. To hold a variable number of items, use `std::vector`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf for a few possible string values that would be an overkill storagewise (though for a really limited set of card types char array is likewise an overkill).

Comment: @bipll: For a few possible values use an enumeration.

Comment: @John3136 by reset i just mean empty the array of items and set each item in the array to 0 in preparation to be written over

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf yes, exactly.

Comment: memset should work ok, but it seems weird to use in c++. How are you using it? and how do you know it doesnt work?

Comment: To use `memset` do `memset(w.cards, 0, sizeof(Card) * 11);`, where `w` is the wallet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may consider using std::vector instead:

```
struct Wallet {
    double money;
    vector<Card> cards;
    int cardIndex;
};
```

You could then use clear() oder assign() methods of std::vector or simply its assignment operator.

But if you insist using fixed size array, you could use std::fill from `<algorithm>` header

for ex.

```
struct Wallet {
    double money;
    Card cards[11];
    int cardIndex;
    void reset() { std::fill(cards, cards+11  Card{}); }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There's always the simple solution.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  wallet.cards[i] = Card();
}
```

Alternatively, as @Cheers notes in the comments, you can use a range-based for loop to have the compiler automatically determine the bounds. This is safer as you can't mistakenly use the wrong size for the array.

```
for (Card& card : wallet.cards) {
  card = Card();
}
```

The magic happens with the ampersand `&`, which makes `card` a reference. So any assignment to the variable `card` affects the original card in the array.

Comment: Instead of a counting loop with a magic constant you can just use a (much safer) range based `for` loop, llike so: `for( Card& card : wallet.cards )`

Comment: Sorry about the edit, I looked at the wrong array in the OP's code. But it sort of illustrates why magic numbers are bad (again, sorry). Rolled it back.